# How to sign the soap body of a request on the client's side

Tags: java, soap, keystore, public-key-encryption, jax-rpc

I have built my Stub and other Web Service Facade classes via `wscompile`. The request can be built with no problems, but once it is sent off, the following error arises:

```
javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException: WSEC5061E: The SOAP Body is not signed.; null
at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.StreamingSender._raiseFault(StreamingSender.java:365)
at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.StreamingSender._send(StreamingSender.java:228)
```

The error clearly states that `The SOAP Body is not signed.` From my knowledge, this seems like I am doing something incorrect with setting the system properties. Below is what properties I have set:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","pkcs12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",KeystorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",KeystorePassword);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",TrustStorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",TrustStorePassword);
```

I have searched a bit about signing the body of a SOAP request with a public key or KeyStore but don't really know much about the topic, so I am probably searching for the wrong keywords.

If anyone could point me in the direction of any information or tutorials it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks